# 目が覚める versus 起きる

Tags: word-choice, meaning

What is the difference between 目{め}が覚{さ}める and 起{お}きる?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

目が覚める → Wake up.

起きる → Rise up.

The main difference comes from the fact that 起きる can mean both "rise up" and "wake up". Hence, objects, and not just animals (including humans) can 起きる.